# TargetElement and Attributes missing in Beta 8?

Tags: asp.net-core

I upgraded a Beta 7 project to Beta 8 and I have on project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime": "4.0.0-beta8"
```

And on a custom TagHelper I have:

```
[TargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteIsName)]
```

But TargetElement and Attributes are not recognized ...

When I change it to:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Razor.Runtime": "4.0.0-beta8-15575"
```

Then both TargetElement and Attributes are recongnized.

The problem is that I start having problems with different builds ...

Where are TargetElement and Attributes in Beta-8 release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In beta8, `TargetElementAttribute` was renamed to `HtmlTargetElementAttribute`:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteIsName)]
```